# How to access folder path from first input parameter and how to call IF Loop in batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

```
@Echo OFF

SET FilePath=%1

SET HeaderFilePath=%2

SET RetrunCode="0"

Call :sub %FilePath% exit /b

:sub SET FileName=%~n1


SET FilePath=%1

SET "FileType=.zip"

CALL SET "ZipType=%%FilePath:%FileType%=%%"

if "%Ext%"==".zip" (goto Function1) else Goto Function2

:Function1
 Echo  File is zipped

:Function2 
Echo File is not zipped

pause
```

**I have place above code in test.bat and passed below mentioned parameter

> C:\Users\ak813708>C:\Users\abhay\Desktop\test1.bat
>   C:\Users\abhay\Desktop\doc1.zip C:\Users\abhay\Desktop\header.txt but
>   regardless of its first parameter file type its calling function2.**

Comment: "if i am passing E:\testing\appserver_output.dat then it should call Function2 and if I am passing E:\testing\appserver_output.zip, It should call only function 1" - So basically you want to branch only on the basis of extension?

Comment: You can get the file extension with `%~x1` - Expand `%1` to a file eXtension only

Comment: @Karan : yes. but in above code I am trying to call fuctions based on If but its not working.

Comment: @DavidPostill : thanks.. now its full proof and easier as previously I was thinking to to find substring ".zip" in the FilePath

Comment: That was what I was asking you about. If it's a simple case of branching according to extension, `for /?` will tell you what %~xI does.

Comment: @Karan :Also If I am passing Remote server path then "PGPProcessPath" is wrong as it will skip remote desktop name..I have used PGPProcessPath=\\%~p1

Comment: Can you just specify clearly what you want the input and output to be? For example if you pass `\\rdwdevapp\testing\appserver_output.dat`, what should be the expected output? I'm asking because it's best to break down the problem into the smallest possible relevant portion. Debugging someone's entire code requires effort and I'd rather it was the last resort.

Comment: @Karan: we are passing Input file which will be either zipped or non-zipped. If its zipped then we need to use function1 else function2. If we pass \\rdwdevapp\testing\appserver_output.dat then output file will be like \\rdwdevapp\testing\appserver_output without extn.

Comment: A simple batch file containing just `@echo %~dpn1` will return `\\rdwdevapp\testing\appserver_output` if you call it like `test.bat \\rdwdevapp\testing\appserver_output.dat`. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I would encourage you to use the `%~dp` operator, instead of just the `%~p` operator.  For a complete list of the file operators, and how to use them, use `FOR /?` on the command line - it's at the very end of the section.

Something like the below should provide you more predictable code which provides a little flexibility in how you accept command line filenames.

```
@Echo OFF
SET File=%1
SET HeaderFilePath=%2
SET RetrunCode="0"
Call :sub %File%
exit /b

:sub 
SET FileName=%~n1
SET Ext=%~x1
SET PGPProcessPath=%~dp1
SET EncryptFile=%~fnx1
SET DecryptFile=%EncryptFile:_pgp=%
pause

if "%Ext%"==".zip" (goto Function1) else Goto Function2
```

Comment: If I pass E:\abhay\test\output1.dat then its giving \abhay\test\ instead of E:\abhay\test..

Comment: So making the changes in my answer produced no change in output?

Comment: ice13berg: its working now... thanks.... but still IF loop is giving error

Comment: @abhayk Please [edit] your question to include the latest code your are using and what `if` error you are now getting...

Comment: @DavidPostill : I have updated my code. But each time its calling only function 2

Comment: @abhayk where are you setting `Ext`?

Comment: That's because %Ext% is unset. See in my code where %Ext% is set to %~x1, which takes the file extension. In your code, %Ext is never set.

Comment: @ice13berg : thanks a lot... Its working now i missed the %Ext% part..

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I get the file extension give a commandline parameter?

You can get the file extension using:

`%~x1` - Expand `%1` to a file eXtension only.

So you can use something like:

```
SET Extension=%~x1

...

If "%ZipType%"=="%Extension%" (goto Function1) else Goto Function2
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF
SET File=%1
SET HeaderFilePath=%2
Call :sub %File%
exit /b
:sub 
SET FileName=%~n1
SET Ext=%~x1
SET PGPProcessPath=%~dp1
SET EncryptFile=%~fnx1
SET DecryptFile=%EncryptFile:_pgp=%
Echo extn is %Ext%
if "%Ext%"==".zip" (goto Function1) else Goto Function2
:Function1
echo this is function 1
goto :eof
:Function2
echo this is function2
goto :eof
:eof
Echo Process is completed
pause
```

I have modified my batch is like this... Now both remote server as well as local desktop paths are getting processed as well IF statement is working perfectly

Comment: I think I answered your questions, originally regarding paths and the IF statement.  Your script was probably running both functions, not JUST Function 2, because when a '.zip' file was processed, Function 1 was called, but no Return code was submitted (and the script did not exit), so it proceeded to run Function 2.  Your `goto :eof` solves, this.  A better solution would be to `return` a code, since you call the function (`call : sub`, and then have an immediate `EXIT /b`.